# Can I use Tails as SOCKS proxy server

Tags: proxy, virtualbox, socks, tor, usb-drive

Tails solves my every requirements except that I need to download and store data. The problem is that it has to run in a virtualbox and I do not know how create a virtual usb drive. So tails doesn't let me persist anything.

I was wondering if it'd be possible to configure tails as a proxy server to Tor network so a more user friendly OS can connect through Tails. I can't edit the ssh_config file since its a LiveCD boot. An easy way to emulate usb drive would solve my problem. Thank you.

Here is the feature request for virtual usb drive: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2230

Comment: Whonix is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Who is what I needed. Here is the comparasion. https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Comparison_with_Others